# how to parallelize the c-program for multi CPU

Tags: c, parallel-processing

The result often times looks wrong, because the 'bmmin' after the parallelization seems to be wrong or something like that..

```
    #pragma omp parallel private(thread_id, bmmin, r ,t, am, b, bm)
    {
    thread_id=omp_get_thread_num();
    bmmin=INFINITY;
    for (i=0; i<nel; i++) {
      am=a[i]+ldigitse*j;
      b=roundl((lval-am)/ldigits0);
      bm=fabsl(am+b*ldigits0-lval);
      if (bm<bmmin) {
        bmmin=bm;
        t[0]=(int)b;
        r=ldigits[0]*t[0];
        for (l=1; l<ndig; l++) {
          t[l]=(*s)[i][l-1];
          r=r+ldigits[l]*t[l];
        };
        t[ndig]=j;
        r=r+ldigits[ndig]*t[ndig];
      };
    };
    // bmmin result looks almost same in many threads, why?
    printf("Thread %d: r=%Lg, bmmin=%Lg, bmmin_glob=%Lg\n",thread_id,powl(10,r),bmmin,bmmin_glob);
    #pragma omp critical
    if (bmmin<bmmin_glob) {
      printf("Thread %d - giving minimum r=%9Lg!\n",thread_id,powl(10,r));
      bmmin_glob=bmmin;
      r_glob=r;
      for (i=0; i<=ndig; i++) {
        t_glob[i]=t[i];
      };
    };
    };
```

When running the code, it outputs as:

```
Initializing the table of the logarithmic constants...
Calculation started for k from 0 to 38...
j,k=-19,0
Thread 7: r=2.57008e+30, bmmin=2.96034e-05, bmmin_glob=inf
Thread 7 - giving minimum r=2.57008e+30!
Thread 1: r=3.74482e+16, bmmin=2.96034e-05, bmmin_glob=inf
Thread 6: r=3.74482e+16, bmmin=2.96034e-05, bmmin_glob=inf
Thread 3: r=3.1399, bmmin=0.000234018, bmmin_glob=inf
Thread 2: r=3.74482e+16, bmmin=2.96034e-05, bmmin_glob=inf
Thread 5: r=3.1399, bmmin=0.000234018, bmmin_glob=inf
Thread 4: r=392.801, bmmin=0.000113243, bmmin_glob=inf
Thread 0: r=3.14138, bmmin=2.96034e-05, bmmin_glob=2.96034e-05
Result:    2.57008e+30
Exponents: 2^129*3^-13*5^16*7^-19
j,k=-18,1
```

with a lot of case that have bmmin=2.96034e-05, even the r-value has a lot of variation.

Answer (score 0):

> `bmmin` result looks almost same in many threads, why?

This is because it is defined as a `private` variable in the parallel section in the code. In fact the same thing applies for `thread_id` and other variables like `r`. A private variable is a variable defined and accessible only from each thread. If you want to make accessible the result of each thread to the main thread, then you need to store the value in an array. Alternatively you can use *OpenMP reductions*.

> [...] looks like the 'i' values are out of the range of the for loop

Variable are *implicitly shared* by default in parallel sections. This means `i` is shared by default. Thus, there is a **race condition on `i`**. You need to put it private or to declare it inside the parallel section so each thread have its own version.

Note that `omp parallel` section does *not* share the work between threads. You need to either use a `parallel for` or to do it yourself (eg. splitting `nel` so each thread compute a part of the loop if this is what you want).

Besides this, `#pragma omp critical` does nothing outside a parallel section. It might be useful to use two directives: a `#pragma omp for` directive to a `#pragma omp parallel` and a `#pragma omp for` ones.

Comment: It looks not going too well. Those variables should be for each thread separately.

Comment: Each thread in my opinion could give diffferent values for r and bmmin, then once thread is done it should go in 'serial manner' to select the thread's value if that is the minimum at the time it passes the #pragma omp critical. I tried to check the manuals, but it seems not too clear.

Comment: Printing the i-value of the for-loop inside the parallel threads:
for (i=0; i<nel; i++) {
      printf("Thread %d:%d\n",i);

It is giving result as:
Thread 30:30
Thread 31:-31317696
Thread 32:16379
Thread 33:16379
Thread 34:-31317696
Thread 35:16379
Thread 36:16376
Thread 37:16379
Thread 38:16379
Thread 39:16377
Thread 59:54
Thread 60:-31317696
Thread 61:-31317696

Which looks like the 'i' values are out of the range of the for loop (i=0; i<nel; i++),
and even negative values of i is plotted here..

Comment: Ok. I just found out that you use `omp parallel` and not `omp parallel for` (hence my comment to split it) and I missread your code. Sorry. I edited the answer to clarify this and explain the issue with `i`. The overall goal of the code is not very clear to me.

Comment: I should upload the whole program,  but it looks not possible.
It is just calculating numeric values (like searching of diophantes equation solution).
I hope I can send it for your inspection..